# Python expanding YouTube uploads

Tags: python, ajax, youtube

So, I'm working on a little program that will automatically check and download new music from a bunch of given YouTube channels. I'm currently working on a way to obtain the links of all the uploaded videos each channel has, which I'm doing like a scraper. (Yes, the YouTube API would probably be the proper way to go, but I don't know how to properly use it yet.)

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request

ytlink = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUvoulvwzCnUVk7yoduI_Gw/videos'
r = urllib.request.urlopen(ytlink).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "html.parser")
links = soup.find_all('a', {"class": "yt-uix-sessionlink yt-uix-tile-link spf-link  yt-ui-ellipsis yt-ui-ellipsis-2"})

for tag in links:
    link = tag.get('href', None)
    if link is not None:
        print(link)
```

This is what I currently have, the problem is, it currently only grabs the first 30 video links since those are the only ones on screen. I've already seen that when the `"Load More"` button is pressed it executes some Ajax which is initiated by some JavaScript. My question is: How can I get Python to keep triggering the `"Load More"` button until all uploads are visible?

Comment: You can't, unless you use a headless browser or similar. Selenium or Python Mechanize is what you should look into for tasks like these, since BeautifulSoup doesn't have the capability to actually parse JS for you.

Comment: Well, that or you get lucky and you find the URL the AJAX call gets sent to, but it's going to be very nasty walking through the minified page source.

Comment: Alright, I'll go look into that. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily mimic the  ajax calls and parse the json output returned, we just need to pull the `/browse_ajax?action_continuation=...` url and keep requesting until it is no longer in the json returned:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from urlparse import urljoin # python 3 -> from urllib.parse import urljoin


def get_links():
    # cretate all css selectors
    ytlink = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUvoulvwzCnUVk7yoduI_Gw/videos'
    ajax_css = "button[data-uix-load-more-href]"
    link_css = "a.yt-uix-sessionlink.yt-uix-tile-link.spf-link.yt-ui-ellipsis.yt-ui-ellipsis-2"
    base = "https://www.youtube.com/"


    r = requests.get(ytlink).content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r, "lxml")

    # yield first visible links
    for link in soup.select(link_css):
        yield urljoin(base, link["href"])

    # Load more button
    ajax = soup.select(ajax_css)[0]["data-uix-load-more-href"]

    while True:
        print(ajax)
        r = requests.get(urljoin('https://www.youtube.com/', ajax))

        # next html is stored in the json.values()
        soup = BeautifulSoup("".join(r.json().values()), "lxml")
        for link in soup.select(link_css):
            yield urljoin(base, link["href"])

        ajax = soup.select(ajax_css)
        # if empty "Load more" button would be gone
        if not ajax:
            break
        ajax = ajax[0]["data-uix-load-more-href"]
```

That would give you all 87 links.

```
In [26]: links = list(get_links())
/browse_ajax?action_continuation=1&continuation=4qmFsgJAEhhVQ1V2b3Vsdnd6Q25VVms3eW9kdUlfR3caJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk1yZ0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D
/browse_ajax?action_continuation=1&continuation=4qmFsgJAEhhVQ1V2b3Vsdnd6Q25VVms3eW9kdUlfR3caJEVnWjJhV1JsYjNNZ0FEZ0JZQUZxQUhvQk03Z0JBQSUzRCUzRA%253D%253D

In [27]: len(links)
Out[27]: 87

In [28]: print(links)
['https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjmzIu4VJEY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecRpNV8Xob8', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdHoaoAhnMo', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oqBKEvdrqE', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIbvfOd34-A', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4G8ge1VO5s', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkW0f2iUOCc', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ex2NIeXfYl8', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMd4pSX-aVs', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZS7KjUjlLWA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEq9sQJLOgg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSgaCowC5TY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV5Ive_zJT4', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snThWzMroaA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ud6YhBCucPg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nSfyivyxdg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7hf2wqpUY4', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVBvxkVt9wc', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcI25yU9yso', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMIZZS8HY8A', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWD3Zi23rIs', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-IbllcTi64', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_tW_UxG8bM', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQd0mopVnQg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mG8NJlsg4rI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsaNY6xpnKY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=839h3eZMSWA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_yytPtWmP0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGESQfB9dYM', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mO5R-1uTJhg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgqLck9SFOc', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCaFEsxd-Y8', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlpMbnOqP20', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bj1QT5bxFlA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMtKCu6a7gQ', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RV6x33mf4WI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhlXuTtmNqE', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TWN1G5e-tg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgjeYTkROyk', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hFkFoOf-aA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH1u_KQapfw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-l-FGDsbjw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFSgyE64Jjw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhDBtfvv2BM', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFgPFi04oTo', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58a45EfYv1g', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtYl5TbK2nc', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TI-1qxoDRnw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0M90HqibHI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Llb19v7QiXU', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqhL_Ms6vuY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFFRgAjXs1Y', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eHFG5AACHI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eVOx8Sw9Jg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9s_XvG3M-UI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzdO01_tKFo', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uA2KkxfSW_U', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29Lt1LQtp5k', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfJ9p5iJGz8', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjMHd1xVlS0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkZ0FISTxkk', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkhD8kYi4MI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bQajpTnOrY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XglzEbcjP8c', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBszbh6Qwag', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVGWndVjCYg', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgJxj2cUoyQ', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaEVwakp_rI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YnpS-IaYCw', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEFSFU2a9CY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jc2aVD4pwnk', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY1dOJEv4j4', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwjXt2pWoBE', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dqn26tWxNsI', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiv6JqGhcCU', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFi47HLPqoM', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1zdWugNdy0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngOBscDs3T4', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RT5dQVZ-VQY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bifExgZW7k0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBEbaEgox1Y', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDy9aGFngkY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i06Iv0k5fVY', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NaRXV7uyPE', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl0nIoLJUU0', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXo0T4dRdgA', 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-7H5Wq0_2Y']
```

I left the `print(ajax)` call in so you can see how it changes.

You could  use  [selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/) with [PhantomJs](http://phantomjs.org/) which would look something like:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException,StaleElementReferenceException


ytlink = 'https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCUvoulvwzCnUVk7yoduI_Gw/videos'
hrefs = "a.yt-uix-sessionlink.yt-uix-tile-link.spf-link.yt-ui-ellipsis.yt-ui-ellipsis-2"
ajax= "button[data-uix-load-more-href]"
dr = webdriver.PhantomJS()
dr.get(ytlink)

while True:
    try:
        load_mode_b = dr.find_element_by_css_selector(ajax)
        load_mode_b.click()
    except StaleElementReferenceException as e:
        print(e)
    except NoSuchElementException as e:
        print(e)
        break
```

Which if we run we see the exact same output:

```
In [32]: l = [a.get_attribute("href") for a in dr.find_elements_by_css_selector(hrefs)]

In [33]: len(l)
Out[33]: 87

In [34]: print(l)
[u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjmzIu4VJEY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ecRpNV8Xob8', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mdHoaoAhnMo', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3oqBKEvdrqE', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIbvfOd34-A', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x4G8ge1VO5s', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EkW0f2iUOCc', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ex2NIeXfYl8', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XMd4pSX-aVs', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZS7KjUjlLWA', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZEq9sQJLOgg', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nSgaCowC5TY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nV5Ive_zJT4', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=snThWzMroaA', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ud6YhBCucPg', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1nSfyivyxdg', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b7hf2wqpUY4', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVBvxkVt9wc', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pcI25yU9yso', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EMIZZS8HY8A', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xWD3Zi23rIs', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-IbllcTi64', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U_tW_UxG8bM', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vQd0mopVnQg', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mG8NJlsg4rI', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PsaNY6xpnKY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=839h3eZMSWA', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q_yytPtWmP0', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oGESQfB9dYM', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mO5R-1uTJhg', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wgqLck9SFOc', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GCaFEsxd-Y8', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VlpMbnOqP20', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bj1QT5bxFlA', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SMtKCu6a7gQ', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RV6x33mf4WI', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WhlXuTtmNqE', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TWN1G5e-tg', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jgjeYTkROyk', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0hFkFoOf-aA', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yH1u_KQapfw', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5-l-FGDsbjw', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sFSgyE64Jjw', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OhDBtfvv2BM', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uFgPFi04oTo', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=58a45EfYv1g', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jtYl5TbK2nc', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TI-1qxoDRnw', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q0M90HqibHI', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Llb19v7QiXU', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sqhL_Ms6vuY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YFFRgAjXs1Y', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8eHFG5AACHI', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_eVOx8Sw9Jg', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9s_XvG3M-UI', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lzdO01_tKFo', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uA2KkxfSW_U', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=29Lt1LQtp5k', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nfJ9p5iJGz8', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cjMHd1xVlS0', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tkZ0FISTxkk', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bkhD8kYi4MI', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_bQajpTnOrY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XglzEbcjP8c', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBszbh6Qwag', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rVGWndVjCYg', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AgJxj2cUoyQ', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TaEVwakp_rI', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-YnpS-IaYCw', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sEFSFU2a9CY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jc2aVD4pwnk', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aY1dOJEv4j4', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bwjXt2pWoBE', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Dqn26tWxNsI', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wiv6JqGhcCU', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IFi47HLPqoM', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N1zdWugNdy0', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ngOBscDs3T4', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RT5dQVZ-VQY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bifExgZW7k0', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fBEbaEgox1Y', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDy9aGFngkY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i06Iv0k5fVY', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2NaRXV7uyPE', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Hl0nIoLJUU0', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iXo0T4dRdgA', u'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=i-7H5Wq0_2Y']
```